# Why isn't my time based trigger working properly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I recorded a simple google sheets macro ( relative reference ) by copying info within a cell and pasting it into the cell below. It works fine when a manually run the macro but when I added a time based trigger ( every minute ) it only runs on the cell "A1" and not the selected cell e.g. B2.

I need the time based trigger so that it works for the selected cell instead.

```
    function copy1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 0).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when it automatically runs, the initial cell is A1. You can overwrite that by saying offset(2,2) on line 4 of your code. Then it should always use that cell. Remember that if you create a relative reference that the currently selected cell will not necessarily be selected when the trigger is running.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE: The time-driven trigger cannot retrieve the current cell

Why?

Because a time-driven trigger runs even if the spreadsheet is closed - in this case there is no current cell, but by default Google Sheets always resets the current cell to A1 when you reopen the spreadsheet - this is the one the tie-driven trigger retrieves.

### Good news: Recently a new trigger has been introduced - [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)

This trigger fires every time you change the selection.

So for example if you click away from `A1` to `B2` - `B2` will be detected as the new selected cell with the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e.range`.

Sample:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var cell = e.range;
   cell.copyTo(cell.offset(1, 0), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
```